# Image is overlapping content after resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to create JS function that resize image by clicking on it. It works but I have problem with overlapping content. After I click on image it will resize and overlap content above and under my image I tried to set width, height, position(absolute) but nothing works. I want to push the content away from image.

```js
let img = document.getElementById("changeImg");
// Function to increase image size
function scaleupImg() {
  // Set image size to 2 times original
  img.style.transform = "scale(2)";
  // Animation effect
  img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
}
```

```css
#changeImg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cool-icon-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean viverra cursus ex, eget                    auctor lectus volutpat sed. Maecenas vel ornare arcu.</p>
  <div class="cool-icon-box">
   <img id="changeImg" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7x5c_f1yzsQ/XHv9FZKHrEI/AAAAAAAADrE/4iGl9Lm6K2odX4SdWbU_RN6gZesx4IaGACEwYBhgL/s1600/html.jpg" alt="" onclick="scaleupImg()">
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean viverra cursus ex, eget auctor lectus volutpat sed. Maecenas vel ornare arcu.</p>
</section>
              
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css scale() function will always overlay neighboring elements. Try this..

```
let img = document.getElementById("changeImg");
 // Function to increase image size
    function scaleupImg() {
       // Set image size to 2 times original
      img.style = "height:100%;width:100%";
      // Animation effect
      img.style.transition = "transform 0.25s ease";
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set transition on the image element in the CSS with `width` as the property to transition. In your code, remove the setting of the transition. When clicking on the image, all you need to do is apply `img.style.width = "100%"`.

The problem with using `scale` is it scales the image in place, thus, it can overlap other elements.

```js
let img = document.getElementById("changeImg");
// Function to increase image size
function scaleupImg() {
  // Set image size to 2 times original
  img.style.width = "100%";
}
```

```css
#changeImg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  transition:width 0.25s ease;
}

.cool-icon-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean viverra cursus ex, eget                    auctor lectus volutpat sed. Maecenas vel ornare arcu.</p>
  <div class="cool-icon-box">
   <img id="changeImg" src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7x5c_f1yzsQ/XHv9FZKHrEI/AAAAAAAADrE/4iGl9Lm6K2odX4SdWbU_RN6gZesx4IaGACEwYBhgL/s1600/html.jpg" alt="" onclick="scaleupImg()">
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>HEADING</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean viverra cursus ex, eget auctor lectus volutpat sed. Maecenas vel ornare arcu.</p>
</section>
              
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is, because positioning by `position: relative` and changes to the element by the `transform`-property are only applied after the element has been inserted into the DOM.
By that I mean that visual changes of the elements achieved by using `position: relative` in combination with the `top`-, `left`-, `right`- and `bottom`-property as well as by using the `transform`-property do not affect the layout of its parent or its siblings. These changes only affect the element itself and its children.